# Date formatting JSON

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, json, date

I have a JSON object with a date 
    "timeStarted":"20160809235348+0300"

which in my MySQL database is `2016-08-09 23:53:48`.

I use JPA Eclipselink and JAX-RS to make the REST. In my model this field is:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)

@Column(name = "time_started")

private Date timeStarted;
```

My problem is how to format this date with AngularJS to be like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: are you try use angular date filter 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date ?

Comment: you storing the timestamp in wrong format in Databade,Its not acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [momentjs](https://github.com/moment/moment) for datetime operations. it is very successful js library.

```
moment("20160809235348+300","YYYYMMDDhhmmss").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: did you check the output?

Comment: glad to hear . can you accept the answer if it works. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
{{date (your date variable) | date:"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}}
```

angular provides date filter, for date formatting.